# Is there a way to position a background image relative to the centre of an element?

Tags: css

I have an element that I wish to apply a background to, though I want the background image to be positioned based on its right co-ordinate.

I could use a container div to represent the background though it's not really practical in this situation.

I presently have the following rule:

```
.myelem {
  background-image: url("myelem.png");
  background-position: 5% 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Which for the most part works because of the size of the image. If it were possible I'd like to have something that specified that the relative position of the background was `middle` instead of `left`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The css propoerty [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position) accepts `center` as a value:

```css
.myelem {
    background-image: url("myelem.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Or the shorthand version:

```css
.myelem {
    background: url("myelem.png") center center no-repeat;
}
```

**Update 1**

There is no simple css way to set the background-position to an offset of center (or bottom or right).

You could add padding to the actual image, use javascript to calculate the position after page load, add margin to the element as suggested in the following SO questions:

- [HTML background image offset by x pixels from the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981842/html-background-image-offset-by-x-pixels-from-the-center)
- [Offset a background image from the right using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142405/offset-a-background-image-from-the-right-using-css)

Alternatively you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) to calculate the correct position. Although [calc is not supported](http://caniuse.com/calc) by all browsers at this point.

Using calc you could do something like this:

```css
.myelem {
    background-image: url("myelem.png");
    background-position: 5% 60%;
    background-position: -webkit-calc(50% - 200px) 60%;
    background-position: calc(50% - 200px) 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrtJW/2/)**

Comment: You could also combine all that into {background: url(...) center center no-repeat}.

Comment: @3dgoo thanks for the update, I did specify "relative to" in the title of my question. Unfortunately as I don't have access to modify the source I can only use CSS. `calc` would be fine though I do also need to support IE 8 and above.

Comment: I've accepted your answer with using calc and fallbacks for percentage based positioning, thanks. I must note that `calc()` requires there be spaces around the operator otherwise it gets ignored (firefox and safari tested).

Comment: You're completely right Brett. The amount of times I've forgotten the whitespace after a minus symbol in `calc` call is so frustrating. Can't believe I did it again.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work in IE9, even though it's supposed to be supported. Triple-checked whitespace around the minus sign and tried both -webkit-calc and just calc.

Comment: Hi @nphx. It works in my IE9 in this test I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/MrtJW/1/. Can you check that this test works for you too? If it works the image's right edge should be aligned to the centre of the red box (along the dashed centre line). If it doesn't work the image should be aligned to the left of the box. If this test does work for you, can you recreate your problem in a fiddle and share it please?

Comment: Hey, @3dgoo! Your fiddle works just fine, but when I copy the code into my project, IE9 starts ignoring the calc again (it works in FF). I've tried marking each property as !important, but to no avail.

Comment: @nphx - Can you try to recreate your problem in a jsfiddle? Or share a link to your project, and we can have a look?