# How to use background-position percentage correctly in this case?

Tags: html, css

I'm about to pull my hair out on this one.

I have a horizontal strip made of different `divs`. Their width is defined by a percentage of the total strip width (which is unknown)

for example:

```
---------------------------------
|     |     |            |      |
---------------------------------
0%   20%   40%          80%    100%
```

Now I want to have a background image which basically spans over the whole strip but I have to define them individually on every div because they might have different variations based on which div it is.

So the first div (0% - 20%) would have a `background-width` of `500%` and a `background-position` of (0, 0)

The second one (20% - 40%) would also have a `background-width` of `500%` and a `background-position` of (25%, 0) (more on that later)

The third one (40% - 80%) would have a `background-width` of `250%` and a `background-position` of (~66.66%, 0)

The last one (80%-100%) would once again have a `background-width` of `500%` and a `background-position` of (100%, 0)

Now this might sound like a really stupid problem but I just can't wrap my head around how to calculate the correct values for the `background-positions` based on the div-width and position on the strip even though I think I roughly understand how the percentage positioning works. I would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Edit: After some scribbling I think I figured it out but I'm not posting it as an answer yet because my brain is too fried to even understand the reasoning behind it. Maybe someone will take the time to explain why this works. I'm certainly going to try after getting some sleep. I'm able to calculate the correct values like this:

```
background_position_x = div_strip_position_x + div_width * div_strip_position_x / (100 - div_width)
```

(All variables are in percentages)

Comment: Why don't you just make set all the div's background to transparent and then set a background for the containing div?

Comment: @Zze Because the actual background-image files might vary from div to div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use percentages in background-position:

> The size of the background positioning area minus size of background image; size refers to the width for horizontal offsets and to the height for vertical offsets

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container#example1>div {
  width: 50%;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
}

.container#example2>div {
  width: 33.33%;
  background-size: 300% 100%;
}

.container#example3>div {
  width: 25%;
  background-size: 400% 100%;
}

#example1 #d1 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x400/333333/000000);
  background-position: 0% 0;
}

#example1 #d2 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x400/666666/000000);
  background-position: 100% 0;
}

#example2 #d1 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x400/333333/000000);
  background-position: 0% 0;
}

#example2 #d2 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x400/666666/000000);
  background-position: 50% 0;
}

#example2 #d3 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x400/999999/000000);
  background-position: 100% 0;
}

#example3 #d1 {
  background-image: url(http://weknownyourdreamz.com/images/park/park-07.jpg);
  background-position: 0% 0;
}

#example3 #d2 {
  background-image: url(http://weknownyourdreamz.com/images/park/park-07.jpg);
  background-position: 33.33% 0;
}

#example3 #d3 {
  background-image: url(http://weknownyourdreamz.com/images/park/park-07.jpg);
  background-position: 66.66% 0;
}

#example3 #d4 {
  background-image: url(http://weknownyourdreamz.com/images/park/park-07.jpg);
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="container">
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <div id="d2"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="example2" class="container">
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <div id="d2"></div>
  <div id="d3"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="example3" class="container">
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <div id="d2"></div>
  <div id="d3"></div>
  <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
```

Lets look at example3.

The "easiest" way to work out what to use for `background-position` with each segment is...

```
100% / (segmentID * (numberOfSegments -1))
```

So in this case, we want 4 **total** segments.

1. `100% / (0 * (4-1))  == 0%`
2. `100% / (1 * (4-1)) == 33.33%`
3. `100% / (2 * (4-1)) == 66.66%`
4. `100% / (3 * (4-1)) == 100%`

Note that this will only work when `background-size: width == numberOfSegments * 100%`.

Comment: As far as I can tell this comes closest to answering the question yet. I figured it out by myself by now and edited my question with the math I was looking for. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @cwry glad you worked it out - I'm just about to add some extra which encompasses uneven distribution as this one only works for even.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm going to accept this answer for now. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, background-positioning is relative to the div itself, not its parent container. So you might have to either use 0 for X or a negative value if you want to offset it, so that the image ends up at the parent's X=0 coordinate. Keep in mind that `box-sizing` will affect the values.

Depending on your project, you might also use CSS3's `calc` function or a JavaScript/jQuery solution.

Here are some links I found that might help you out:

- [Is there a way to position a background image relative to the centre of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468574/is-there-a-way-to-position-a-background-image-relative-to-the-centre-of-an-eleme)
- [Offset a background image from the right using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142405/offset-a-background-image-from-the-right-using-css)
- http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/image/css-understanding-percentage-background-position.html

Here is [an MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position?v=control) for further information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The values in the question are correct. I was just looking for a way to get there mathematically.

Comment: @cwry, thank you! I apologise that I misinterpreted your question and was not particularly helpful. Another thing I wanted to suggest was for you to maybe use spans instead of divs for the child blocks, as that would make a bit more sense semantically.

Answer (score 0):

1- Wrap them in a parent div.
2- Make their displays "inline-block" and vertical-align "middle".
3- Apply the background image to all.
4- Set the background-size and position for each individually.

```css
.row-1{
  display:block;
  font-size:0;
}
.row-1 > div{
text-align:center;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
background: url('http://www.imagestowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Background-Image-CSS4.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.w20{
   width:20%;
   background-color:red;
   font-size:13px
}
.w40{
   width:40%;
   font-size:13px;
}
.w20.first{
    background-position:0 0;
    background-size: 500%;
}
.w20.second{
   background-position:25% 0;
   background-size: 500%;
}
.w20.third{
   background-position:66.66% 0;
   background-size: 250%;
}
.w20.forth{
   background-position:100% 0;
   background-size: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-1">
  <div class="w20 first">1</div>
  <div class="w20 second">2</div>
  <div class="w40 third">3</div>
  <div class="w20 forth">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I think you misunderstood the question. The essence of my question was how to calculate the background position values not how to implement it in css. I'm sorry If I wasn't clear enough.