# How can I repeat the edge pixels of an image into infinity?

Tags: javascript, css

This image explains what I want:

[image: screenshot]

Of course I could achieve this in photoshop, but I want it to work for infinite width, so that's why I'd like to be able to achieve this via css or javascript.

How can this be done?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Open your image editor.

Crop the image to the `1px` you want.

Insert as `background-image` and style with `repeat-X`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeaty

**EDIT 1**

Based on the following answer:

[put background image in center and repeat last pixel to left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087412/put-background-image-in-center-and-repeat-last-pixel-to-left-and-right)

You could try the `border-image-source` style.