# Safari Background Image Quirk

Tags: html, css, safari

So it seems Safari (latest version) does not like the following code involving a background image:

```
div.nav_element.pdf
{
    background-image:url("/images/pdf_icon.png");
    background-position: right 19px bottom 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

<div class="nav_element pdf">
    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Summary of Product Characteristics</a>
</div>
```

It tells me that my `background-position` property is invalid via that little yellow exclamation point box. Has anybody seen this before? Does it not like relative sizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use this webkit hack:

```
background-position: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px) center; /* Sf 6 */
```

as described in this question:

[Position a CSS background image x pixels from the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197250/position-a-css-background-image-x-pixels-from-the-right)

as referenced by Artem above.

Answer (score 1):

because your background-position property is invalid. it have only 2 values, not 4.
read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197250/position-a-css-background-image-x-pixels-from-the-right)

Comment: I don't see anything of interest there. Could you elaborate?

Comment: you can't place background at 19px from right of div using only background position. in this topic info how you can make it.
background-position: right bottom;  border-right: 19px solid transparent; border-bottom: hmm i dont know how to place%;